# Ansible Copy Module Fails

Tags: copy, ansible

I am trying to copy over the "resolve.conf" file from one machine to another and overwrite the old one. This operation works on all but 4 of the 40+ servers... I get an error it could not replace the file because it is not permitted. I have pasted the contents of the Playbook related to the failure of the operation below.

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root

...

  - name: Copy over the updated DNS configuration file
    copy: src=/etc/resolv.conf dest=/etc/resolv.conf
```

It gives me the following error message for all 4 servers.

> fatal: [server-name]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "checksum": "9925f1a81f849f373f860c3156d19edcd1c002f2", "failed": true, "msg": "Could not replace file: /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1469481567.72-275811900408782/source to /etc/resolv.conf: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted"}

I just don't understand what the problem could be since I am accessing the machines as the root user and the Playbook succeeds on the majority of the servers - many with the exact same configuration and settings. For example, it succeeds on the server "server-analytical1" but fails on the server "server-analytical2". So, does anyone have any insight into why the Playbook would fail for only a few servers even though they're similar to or the same as other servers that succeeded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is the immutable bit set on the target file? Try `lsattr /etc/resolv.conf` and `chattr -i /etc/resolv.conf` to unset if it is.

Comment: That was it! Not sure how those bits ended up getting set, but it solved the problem I was having. Thank you!

Comment: I've seen some distros that generate resolv.conf set that to further discourage manual hacking on the file (in addition to the "DON'T EDIT THIS FILE" comments all over it).